# Is there a reason Subjuntive 1 is not used in this sentence "Mir wurde gesagt, dass du hier bist. Was ist passiert?"

Tags: subjunctive

From Rosetta Stone:

> Mir wurde gesagt, dass du hier bist. Was ist passiert?

instead of

> Mir wurde gesagt, dass du hier seiest. Was ist passiert?

Is this a grammatical error or is the use of subjunctive 1 optional or is there another reason?